# i want make iphone app that uses google credentials to login to my app

Tags: iphone

i have gone through GDATA objective c client library.but i did not able to achieve this.
can any one help me.code snippets are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766643/using-google-reader-api-and-oauth-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

GData Objective is what you are looking for

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/